# How to add a border inside a uiview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am having a uiview and I would like to add a border iside this UIVIew approximately 75 % of UIView. Could any one help with this. I could get the solution to draw the border outside.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well there isn't simply a little property you can set to align the border to the outside. It draws aligned to the inside because the UIViews default drawing operations draw within its bounds.

The simplest solution that comes to mind would be to expand the UIView by the size of the border width when applying the border:

```
CGFloat borderWidth = 2.0f;

self.frame = CGRectInset(self.frame, -borderWidth, -borderWidth);
self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor;
self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth;
```

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be `CGRectInset(self.frame, borderWidth, borderWidth)`?

Comment: @lulian See documentation for CGRectInset ("To create an inset rectangle, specify a positive value. To create a larger, encompassing rectangle, specify a negative value.")

Answer (score 7):

@aroragourav's answer for Swift 3+

```
let borderWidth: CGFloat = 2

frame = frame.insetBy(dx: -borderWidth, dy: -borderWidth)
layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
```